# Restoring a deleted Orphan remote Branch in Git?

Tags: git

How can I restore an Orphan remote branch that was deleted remotely & no has it anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There's no *obvious* way to do it.

Keep in mind that a branch is simply a pointer to a commit.
Thus, if someone had locally the last commit of that branch, he can do a `git reflog`, find the commit, and `cherry-pick` it where he wants.

Comment: That's what I expected, cause I tried `git reflog` with no luck. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout orphan_branch
git push origin orphan_branch
```